# Update the page using FutureBuilder() + GetBuilder()

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, flutter-state

Is there a way to update the state when I use both Getbuilder() + FutureBuilder()

I have list of users in firebase document,
I display these users using Futurebuilder

I want when i click on any user, that user get deleted
I managed to delete the user successfully from firebase but in the UI the user is still shown, so i need to go back and refresh the page.

Here is an example

```dart
    GetBuilder<BlockedAccountController>(
              builder: (controller) {
                return FutureBuilder(
                    future: controller.userDoc,
                    builder: ((context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data!["blockusers"].length,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Container(
                              color: mainappColor,
                              height: 50,
                              width: double.infinity,
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                                    child: Text(
                                      snapshot.data!["blockusers"][index],
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                                    child: InkWell(
                                      onTap: () async {
                                        await unblockAccount(currentusername,
                                            snapshot.data!["blockusers"][index]);
                                        controller.refresh();
                                      },
                                      child: Container(
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            color: Colors.purple,
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                                Radius.circular(5))),
                                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                                        width: 80,
                                        height: 40,
                                        child: Text("unblock".tr),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      } else {
                        return Text("");
                      }
                    }));
              },
            )
```

And the controller

```dart
    class BlockedAccountController extends GetxController {
      late Future<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> userDoc;
    
      void refresh() {
        update();
      }
    
      @override
      void onInit() {
        userDoc = FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("users")
            .doc(currentusername)
            .get();
    
        super.onInit();
      }
    }
```

When I click the button to unBlock the user the UI does not refresh, why?

Thank you.

Comment: Use `StreamBuilder` instead for `FutureBuilder` to get the live update from firebase.

Comment: i am trying to avoid using stream to reduce the reads from firebase.
im looking for a way to trigger update() such as setsate()